# Added prefix for sections but want to suppress the prefix in equation numbering

Tags: sectioning, equations, numbering

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{Problem~\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\section{Relativity}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

And the results:

[image]

How to suppress the "Problem" in the numbering to be (1.1)?

Comment: `\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid updating the section number representation as it may be used elsewhere. Instead, update the section number format `\@seccntformat` which is used when setting the section title:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{physics}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Problem~\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Relativity}

\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This will also set `\subsection`s (and lower units) with the `Problem` prefix.

---

It also may suffice to only call

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
```